# Flaskwebgui not visible on network

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I am trying to use flaskwebgui as a GUI on my Linux device, but I also want it to be accessible for other network devices. I am using flask socketio which works fine. But now when adding flaskwebgui I can no longer browse from other devices. How do I get this working? My flaskUI:

```
FlaskUI(app=self.app, fullscreen=True, maximized=True, port=80, socketio=self.socketio).run
```

The self.app and self.socketio all work fine before I tried FlaskUI.

Comment: Flask-SocketIO does not have any conflicts as far as I know. The problem could be between FlaskWebGUI and your web server. If you are using either eventlet or gevent you may want to try monkey patching the standard library to see if that helps. Unfortunately I cannot give you more details, as I don't have any familiarity with FlaskWebGUI.

Comment: Yea it seems flaskwebgui doesn’t allow the webserver. Only when deploying it this is possible. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Hi @daggarz did you find a way to make it work? I am struggling with it too...